# Passport Authentication Issues

Tags: node.js, express-session, passport-local, passport-local-mongoose

I'm working with NodeJS and learning how to authenticate users and have sessions. I'm using the following packages: express-session, passport, passport-local, passport-local-mongoose

I have gone through the processes:

```
onst app = express();

app.use(express.static("public"));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.use(session({
    secret: process.env.SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// connect to MongoDB
mongoose.set('strictQuery', true);
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/secretsDB');

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
});

userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);
const User = new mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

// PASSPORT - serializer and deserializer
passport.use(User.createStrategy());

passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());

app.post("/register", function(req, res){
    console.log(req.body.username, req.body.password);

    User.register({username: req.body.username}, req.body.password, function(err, user) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.redirect("/register")
        } else {
            console.log("successfully registered user")

            const authenticate = User.authenticate();
            authenticate(req.body.username, req.body.password, function(err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    res.redirect("/secrets")
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

but it keeps showing this err on the terminal:

even though the test to see if the password request is correct logs correctly the username and password as requested

```
Server started on PORT 3000
user@test 1234
Error: User validation failed: password: Path `password` is required.
    at ValidationError.inspect (/home/akpet/udemy/Secrets - Starting Code/node_modules/mongoose/lib/error/validation.js:50:26)
    at internal/per_context/primordials.js:23:32
    at formatValue (internal/util/inspect.js:783:19)
    at inspect (internal/util/inspect.js:337:10)
    at formatWithOptionsInternal (internal/util/inspect.js:2017:40)
    at formatWithOptions (internal/util/inspect.js:1899:10)
    at console.value (internal/console/constructor.js:323:14)
    at console.log (internal/console/constructor.js:358:61)
    at /home/akpet/udemy/Secrets - Starting Code/app.js:79:21
    at /home/akpet/udemy/Secrets - Starting Code/node_modules/passport-local-mongoose/index.js:247:63 {
  errors: {
    password: ValidatorError: Path `password` is required.
        at validate (/home/akpet/udemy/Secrets - Starting Code/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:1346:13)
        at SchemaString.SchemaType.doValidate (/home/akpet/udemy/Secrets - Starting Code/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:1330:7)
        at /home/akpet/udemy/Secrets - Starting Code/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:2905:18
        at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:77:11) {
      properties: [Object],
      kind: 'required',
      path: 'password',
      value: undefined,
      reason: undefined,
      [Symbol(mongoose:validatorError)]: true
    }
  },
  _message: 'User validation failed'
}
```

I have gone through the whole code over and over again, but I have not been able to create a new user, followed it again with the tutorial video I am using, still no difference

Comment: please share the code of User.register method

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with the following line

```
// you're attaching the password incorrectly.
User.register({username: req.body.username}, req.body.password, ...
```

It should be

```
User.register({username: req.body.username, password: req.body.password} ...
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: it has thrown up a new error...

Comment: (node:60705) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "password" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView. Received type function ([Function (anonymous)])

Comment: @kmoakpet please share the code of User.register method

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem came from this:

```js
onst app = express();
```

instead of:

```js
const app = express();
```